# How can I solve this dependency issue in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I started building a project in android studio and I faced this issue after adding some firebase authentication dependency .. and there seems a curved red line under 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' .

this is the gradle app code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aden.adenmarket"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is the project gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

................
and this is the output error:

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be
>   smaller than version 16 declared in library
>   [com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0]
>   C:\Users\PC.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ce1ab53339b3343f02313d46e1b6166b\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 15    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 16,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.auth" to force usage (may
>   lead to runtime failures)

Answer (score 0):

try to change minSdkVersion to 16.

Comment: ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-29:19 to override.

Comment: you cannot mix androidx and anroid.support libraries! Either you use the old android.support stuff or you switch completely to androidx

Comment: how can I switch to androidx ?

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aden.adenmarket"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }
```

change minSDK to 16 in gradle file
If you have other Loacal Libraries with gradles, change those as well

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3

Comment: I copied and paste your code and replaced them ... the previous error has disappeared but then this error occured: 
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3
 I don't know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: @DangerZone change that to v7:28.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Update the project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion 28.0.3
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aden.adenmarket"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also update other dependencies if it shows in lint.

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3

Comment: I have updated the project level build.gradle. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Edited both gradle fies. try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use firebase >= 17.0.0, you must migrate to androidx

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate